# scanf not working well with my code on structs

Tags: c, struct, dev-c++

I am doing the exercises in "Programming in C" book, 3rd Edition, by Steven G.Kochan. Currently working on Chapter 9 -Working with structs. The main part of the question is below, the formula in the code was provided in the question:

> Write a program that permits the user to type in two dates and then
>   calculates the number of elapsed days between the two dates.Try to
>   structure the program logically into separate functions. For example,
>   you should have a function that accepts as an argument a date
>   structure and returns the value of N. This function can then be called twice,
>   once for each date, and the difference taken to determine the number of 
>   elapsed days.

The code I have written is also below....but it is not working as it should: I have an image attached as proof please help me figure out what the issue is [output screen showing that it doesn't allow me enter the second date.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GxzMn.jpg)

```
#include <stdio.h>
struct date
    {
        int day;
        int month;
        int year;
    };          

//function declarations
    int f (struct date thisDate);
    int g (struct date thisDate);

int main(void)
{


    //declarations and initializations
    struct date theDate, otherDate;
    int N1, N2, days;



    printf("Enter the first Date (dd/mm/yyyy):");
    scanf("%i/%i/%i", &theDate.day, &theDate.month, &theDate.year);

    // compute N1 
    N1 = (1461 * f(theDate) ) / 4 + (153 * g(theDate)) / 5 + 3;  //this can be replaced with a function


    printf("\nEnter the  second Date (dd/mm/yyyy):");
    scanf("%i/%i/%i", &otherDate.day, &otherDate.month, &otherDate.year);

    // compute n2 
    N2 = (1461 * f(otherDate) ) / 4 + (153 * g(otherDate)) / 5 + 3;  //this can be replaced with a function

    days = N2 - N1;
    printf("\nThere are %i days between these two dates",days);

    return 0;
}

int f (struct date thisDate)
    {
        if (thisDate.month <= 2)
            {
                return thisDate.year - 1;
            }
        else
            {
                return thisDate.year;
            }
    }

int g (struct date thisDate)
    {
        if ( thisDate.month <= 2)
            {
                return thisDate.month + 13;                 
            }
        else
            {
                return thisDate.month + 1;
            }
    }
```

Comment: Please don't post pictures of images for text programs.  Copy and paste the text as text; indent it as if it were code.

Comment: The code fragment `(1461 * f(theDate) ) / 4 + (153 * g(theDate)) / 5 + 3;` is repeated; it should be part of a function.

Comment: The input string (from the image) is `03/09/2007`; the second input doesn't wait for anything new to be entered before doing the calculation.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the image, the input string is `03/09/2007`; the second input doesn't wait for anything new to be entered before doing the calculation.

The problem is that you used `%i` which reads octal, hexadecimal or decimal numbers.  Octal numbers are indicated by a leading zero; `09` therefore translates to a `0` for the month (because `9` is not a valid octal digit; `08` would also give problems) and then fails the conversion (no `/` after that 0.  The next input starts with the `9` and the `2007` and then doesn't find a `/` so it stops.

Multiple morals:

1. Check the return value from `scanf()`.  In this code, make sure it returns 3; if not, something has gone wrong.
2. Don't use `%i` to read date values; use `%d`.  People don't use octal, and they do enter `09` (and `08`) on occasion.
3. Validate the numbers you read.  Printing them out is helpful — it allows you to see whether the program got what you expected it to get.